# How do I use function keys on a Mac?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I recently switched my whole system to Mac OSX (Snow Leopard 10.6) from Windows 7. Now I've installed *WoW* and imported my old configs/addons without any problems, besides that my keybindings from <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F7</kbd> are completely overriden by some Mac functions like brightness/sound/keyboard backlight etc.

How can I use my F-Keys in games?

Comment: I feel this question really belongs on Ask Different - it seems to have much more to do with Apple than with gaming.

Comment: The origin of my question was related to WoW only, because I thought this was WoW specific keybindings. But it turns out to be more general configuration, so my question was edited. Nevertheless I think it suits here quite well, when some is wondering why their keys in games doesn't work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The option you want is in the Keyboard pane of your System Preferences:

[image: Screenshot]

Unfortunately this applies to *all* applications, not just WoW, which is kind of a pain because almost no other Mac OS X apps use the function keys for anything.

Comment: I'm sure there's a way to get quicksilver to turn that on and off with a few key-presses.

Comment: You can try FNable (https://fnable.com). It will toggle this setting automatically based on the frontmost application.

Answer (score 4):

Use <kbd>Option</kbd> + Function-Key for the <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F10</kbd> on Mac OS X.

Comment: It should be <kbd>Option</kbd>, not ALT.

Comment: The option key has "alt" printed on it (on most recent Macs)

Answer (score 1):

For me it is <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> in Mac OS X v10.6.8.